# How to delete directory from iOS app sandbox

Tags: ios, iphone, directory, sandbox

Suppose I created a folder in "Documents" folder in my application sandbox and I called it "ID123".

From NSFileManager Class Reference I found out that I can create a new folder with one of these methods:

```
– createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:
– createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:
```

The question is how can I delete created directory?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [removeItemAtPath:error:  **OR** removeItemAtURL:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/removeItemAtPath%3aerror%3a) for doing this.

Like:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:yourPath error:nil];
```

or you can use:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:yourPathURL error:nil];
```

Comment: Using URL based methods are the preferred approach.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you're using the URL or path based approach, either use the...

```
- (BOOL)removeItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

or

```
- (BOOL)removeItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL error:(NSError **)error
```

...NSFileManager method.

For example:

```
NSError *removalError = nil;
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:pathToFile error:&removalError]) {
    // Something went wrong.
    NSLog(@"%@", [removalError localizedDescription]);
}
```

In terms of recursive removal the supplied path (or URL depending on the method) can point at a directory containing items/sub-folders, etc. As per the Apple docs:

> A path string indicating the file or directory to remove. If the path
>   specifies a directory, the contents of that directory are recursively
>   removed.

Incidentally, this is clearly defined within the "Creating and Deleting Items" section of the [NSFileManager Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/removeItemAtURL%3aerror%3a), so it would probably be worth the time to give that document a quick overview.

Comment: Ah... the joy of the spineless downvote without a reason. :-)